# Argument name using argparse

Tags: python, argparse

```
# import the necessary packages
import argparse
# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-n", "--name", required=True,
    help="name of the user")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
# display a friendly message to the user
print("Hi there {}, it's nice to meet you!".format(args["name"]))
```

If I run this code with `-h`, I get:

```
$ python simple_example.py --help
usage: simple_example.py [-h] -n NAME
optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -n NAME, --name NAME  name of the user
```

What does `NAME` mean, which comes after `-n` and `--name`? It was nowhere specified in code to use the string 'NAME' anywhere, how did it turn up here? It would have made some sense if it was 'name' but not 'NAME'.

Comment: It's a placeholder for the value the user supplies. It's configurable, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#metavar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NAME` indicates the actual argument you need to pass. This is a way to distinguish between flags that require arguments like `-n` (e.g. - `-n Kyathari` would be valid, `-n` on itself would not be) and flags that don't take arguments like `-h`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but what is a flag? I am unable to understand it by googling

Comment: @KyathariHrushikesh A flag is another term for a command-line option (like `-n` or `-h`)